# How to view the CRViewer in Monitor full Screen?

Tags: vb6

Using VB 6 and Crystal Report 8.5

I am using CRViewer Control in my project and I’m using 15 Inch Monitor, when I run my project in 17 Inch Monitor, CRViewer control not displaying full Screen.

How to set a CRViewer Control according to the Monitor Size?

Need VB 6 Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Set the form the CRViewer is in to open Maximized
2) Resize the CRViewer to the form's size in the Form_Resize event.